# registers same email which is alreday registerd Django Login Signup Project

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I have a Django project login and signup it gives error when a new user enters same username which is already registered but accept the email which is already registered , how to avoid email if it is already registred ??? Can someone help in this issue?
I AM USING CRUD AND LOGIN SIGNUP IN SAME PROJECT .

`My views.py code`

```
def signup_page(request):
    # try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
           
            uname = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            pass2 = request.POST.get('password2')
            pass1 = request.POST.get('password1')
            if pass1 != pass2:
                return HttpResponse("Your password and confirm password are not Same!!")
            else:
                my_user = User.objects.create_user(uname,email,pass1)
                my_user.save()
                messages.info(request,"Signup is Succesfully")
                return redirect(reverse('login_page'));   
        return render (request,'registartion.html')
    # except Exception as e:
    #     raise ValueError("Account With this Username or Email is already registered")

def login_page(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            pass1 = request.POST.get('pass')
            user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=pass1)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,"Succesfully Login")
                return redirect(reverse('dashboard_page'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse ("INCORRECT USERNAME OR PASSWORD")

        return render (request,'login.html')
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect Username Or Password !!!")
```

`MY MODELS.PY`

```
class Members(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICEs =(
    ('Male','Male'),
    ('Female','Female')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=False,unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(null=True,blank=False,max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICEs, max_length=10)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.email} {self.role}'
```

I WANT THAT IF A USER ENTERS A EMAIL WHICH IS ALREADY REGISTERED IT WILL GIVE A MESSAGE THAT EMAIL IS ALREADY REGISTERED .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent users from registering with an email that is already registered in your Django project, you can make use of Django's built-in authentication and User model. Here's how you can modify your signup view in views.py to check for duplicate emails and provide a message if the email is already registered:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages

def signup_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('password1')

        if pass1 != pass2:
            return HttpResponse("Your password and confirm password are not the same!!")
        else:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.error(request, "This email is already registered.")
                return redirect(reverse('signup_page'))
            else:
                my_user = User.objects.create_user(uname, email, pass1)
                my_user.save()
                messages.success(request, "Signup is successfully")
                return redirect(reverse('login_page'))

    return render(request, 'registartion.html')
```

In the updated code, we first check if a user with the provided email already exists in the User model using `User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()`. If an existing user is found with the provided email, we display an error message using `messages.error` and redirect the user back to the signup page. Otherwise, the user is registered as usual.

Make sure you have the messages framework set up properly in your Django project's settings.

This code will ensure that users cannot register with an email that is already registered, and they will receive a message informing them of this issue.

Comment: Thank You So Much FoR helping And Suggesting.IT WOrked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
class Members(forms.Form):
    // other fields
    email = forms.EmailField()
    // other fields

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered.")
        return email
```

Comment: Thank For the Suggesting Problem Resolved !